# Difference between memory allocation and paging in modern operating systems

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory

I've been doing research on operating systems lately, particularly regarding memory management. However, I'm not sure what the difference is between memory management schemes like those found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management such as memory pools or the buddy system, and components of virtual memory, such as paging. Do they both accomplish the same thing or different things? How are they typically implemented in modern operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

They are complementary. Memory management generally refers to how virtual address space is allocated to hold objects in a program. The goal is to reduce fragmentation.

Virtual memory is a system that allows processes to beleive they have more memory then actually exists, allows processes to share parts of their memory without worrying about protecting the rest and so on. The OS's job here is to decide which pages should be backed by physical memory, and how to swap out ones that aren't in use.

Comment: so you're saying that the operating system constructs virtual memory from RAM and from the disk, and then this virtual memory is then used by memory allocation policies such as the buddy system to allocate memory for processes?

Comment: Virtual memory just represents the location of an abstract piece of data. When the CPU tries to fetch it, it will check if it is in memory. If not, it asks the OS to find the data and put it in memory. So a given virtual address could represent data that is at any given point in time located in RAM, on disk, or theoretically even on another machine entirely (though the latency would be horrible in this case).

Comment: Oh ok, but it still is virtual memory that is used by the buddy system and other policies to allocate memory for processes right?